# Going from one-to-one relation to one-to-many in Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am building a Swift iOS app using `Swift 2.1.1` and `RealmSwift 0.97.1`. My initial requirements involved a one-to-one relation between classes `A` and `B` so I wrote the following:

```
class A: Object {
    dynamic var b: B? // A has one B
}

class B: Object {
    var a: A {
        return linkingObjects(A.self, forProperty: "b")[0]
    }
}
```

This worked well but now my requirements have changed and I need a one-to-many relation:

```
class A: Object {
    var bs: [B] {
        return linkingObjects(B.self, forProperty: "a")
    }
}

class B: Object {
    dynamic var a: A? // B belongs to A
}
```

I have users with real data so I would really like to push out this change gracefully using migrations.

From what I have tried, it's not possible to change a relation from within a migration (I get `Can not add objects from a different Realm`). Is this actually the case?

As a workaround, I create a dictionary that maps A primary keys to B primary keys. This also means I had to add a primary key to B which didn't previously have one. Then, outside the migration, I change the order of the relation:

```
for (aKey, bKey) in keyMap {
    let a = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(A.self, key: aKey)
    let b = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(B.self, key: bKey)

    b?.a = a
    a?.b = nil
}
```

This works but I can't seem to get rid of `A`'s `b` property. If I try to remove it, the part of the migration that builds the dictionary fails: there is no link between `A`s and `B`s if I use `newObject` and there is no primary key for `B` if I use `oldObject`. This all would work fine if I could sequence the updates (first add the primary key, then build the dictionary, then delete the `b` property) but I don't think that's possible.

Is there a better way to approach making this change? If not, is there a way I can remove the `b` property?

Comment: Wouldn't be easier if you reverse the way you doing. means leave the `B` has the linking to `bs` and `A` has `List<B>`.
  `class A: Object {
    let bs = List<B>()
}

class B: Object {
    var a: A {
        return linkingObjects(A.self, forProperty: "bs")
    }
}`
Then you may be able to append the `oldObject["b"]` to the `newObject["bs"]`.

Comment: @Ismail - at first glance, I think I'll run into a similar problem with removing the `b` property but it's a good idea. I'll work through it and report back.

Comment: When I do something like `let bs = newObject?["bs"] as? List<MigrationObject>`
`bs?.append((oldObject?["b"])! as! MigrationObject)` in the migration, I get the error `Object is already persisted in a Realm`. So to get this kind of solution to work, I also need to save the primary keys and change the relation outside the migration meaning I can't remove the `b` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of your `B` objects are linked to by exactly one `A` object, you can do the following in your migration:

```
migration.deleteData("B")
migration.enumerate("A") { oldObject, newObject in
    let b = migration.create("B", value: oldObject!["b"]!)
    (newObject!["bs"] as! List<MigrationObject>).append(b)
}
```

This works around the fact that you can't get a reference to the linked object which is compatible with `newObject` without keeping the property `b` by instead deleting all of the existing `B` objects and instead linking to new copies of them.